# brotli with Apache and PHP on Ubuntu 20.04 - possible?

Tags: apache, brotli

I've tried enabling brotli with Apache on Ubuntu 20.04. It works, but not for content generated with PHP.

It works for HTML files:

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" https://server.tld/pp.html 2>&1 | grep content-encoding
< content-encoding: br
```

But does not work if it's PHP - in this case, the content is compressed with "gzip":

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" https://server.tld/pp.php 2>&1 | grep content-encoding
< content-encoding: gzip
```

Curiously, it does work with PHP if I specify "br" as the only value in "Accept-Encoding" (browsers however use "gzip, deflate, br"):

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept-Encoding: br" https://server.tld/pp.php 2>&1 | grep content-encoding
< content-encoding: br
```

So, what is the problem here?

I've enabled brotli by running:

```
a2enmod brotli
```

and adding the following part to the vhost (followed by apache restart):

```
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
```